# React.js controlled text cursor focus issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numbers

I have a simple controlled input of type number like below.

```
<input type="number" value={+value} step={1} onChange={this.updateMyChange} />
```

My `value` often returns a decimal number like `123.123` . My problem is, when I try edit the value. The cursor loses focus and shifts to the beginning ignoring the whole numbers as soon as the decimal places are cleared. Like below:

[image]

How do I address this? Immediately after the decimal places are cleared, the cursor jumps to the beginning thereby making it impossible to edit the whole numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
Below is the remaining code as requested by the user below.

```
render() {
   const {value} = this.state;

   return (
      <input type="number" value={+value} step={1} onChange={this.updateMyChange} />
   )
}
```

And my updateMyChange method is simply

```
updateMyChange(e) {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
}
```

It does nothing much simply sets the new value. The cursor position jumps to the end as soon as decimal places are cleared. It does not set cursor for whole numbers.

Comment: Show more of your code, maybe the entire component

Comment: @NicolaPedretti pls see my update above.

Comment: take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/e6z9z260/

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon thanks for the help. Your example doesn't allow decimal places. Another question, is the refs necessary ? What happened if i don't put ? I haven't use it or seen it before and is wondering.

Comment: sorry, i just focused on the cursor part since seemed your biggest concern. here is the updated example. https://jsfiddle.net/bsoku268/ using refs is the recommended way of accessing elements in react.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon it still persists if you use `type="number"`. This issue seems to be a bug in the react lib itself since there are [several reported](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1698) bugs pertaining similar issues because of out of order rendering/inconsistencies.

Comment: then you might want not to use a number type. use a regular input and provide controls ;) to simulate a number type

Comment: This issue wasn't present on `v15.0.1`, so you have the option of downgrading React version just slightly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how React updates an input field's value:

```
node.setAttribute(attributeName, '' + value);
```

When you set `value` attribute using that method, the caret goes to the beginning of the field, regardless of using React. You can see what I am saying in this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5v896g3q/
(Just try and position the cursor in the field, between changes).

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), `setAttribute` is unstable when dealing with `value`. The recommended way of changing `value` is by accessing the `value` property of the element, like `element.value = newValue`. If you use that approach, all seems to go as expected.

This is all I can tell for sure. Now let's speculate a little. When you type anything in that field, you are:

1. updating the value of the input
2. reading that value, and sending to React as state
3. React updates the value of the input, with the new state

When you are typing on the field, step 3 is likely to have no impact, because when the value comes back, the input already got it right. Except on the case with the float number. When your field reads `1.`, the actual value React updates the field with is `1`. And React uses the evil method (`setAttribute`).

So, a workaround I found was setting the value of the field, using the proper method, before React touches it, on `componentWillUpdate`:

```
componentWillUpdate(nProps, nState){
  this.refs.input.value = '0' + nState.value
}
```

The problem there, is that it is "numerizing" the value on every change, meaning I won't be able to have a point (`1.`). For that reason, I will only edit the input in case new value is 2 characters shorter than the old one (point + digit after point):

```
componentWillUpdate(nProps, nState){
  if(this.state.value.length - nState.value.length === 2){
    this.refs.input.value = '0' + nState.value
  }
}
```

**Working example** - https://jsfiddle.net/bsoku268/3/

note: the fiddle is for demonstration purposes, and not supposed to be a bulletproof solution, as there are many ways of interacting with an input field, such as copy & paste, drag & drop, autofill, etc

Comment: can be the above be achieved in `componentWillReceiveProps`? I intend to use this.setState instead of refs. Why do i need to use refs in this case considering i am using the state itself. ?

Comment: I guess it would work with `componentWillReceiveProps`, but will receive props, doesn't necessarily mean it will update, so I think `componentWillUpdate ` is the right place for this hack. About the `refs`, it is being used to manipulate the DOM, not the state. You could save a reference to the input field via `event.target` if `refs` make you uncomfortable, but the idea is that we change the DOM value to what React would change (which is already in state), but before React does it, So when React gets to it, it doesn't ruin the experience with `setAttribute `

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I asked because we don't usually use the refs , we prefer the to use the state. In the case of `componentWillUpdate` will update above, i am aware that `event.target` would be available in the `componentWillUpdate` . Also the `setState` props cannot be call. So , i guess `refs` is the only way we can manipulate the DOM in this case or could there be any solution without refs? Thanks once again

Comment: have a look at the example without refs - https://jsfiddle.net/bsoku268/4/
But honestly, I would downgrade React's version, as I mentioned in my comment on your question. This feels so hacky...